# Graphics.h library causes many errors?

Tags: c++, dev-c++, bgi

I have a source file in C++ with the header file

```
#include<graphics.h>
```

It seems that the library of Graphics wasn't in the `include` folder , I downloaded it from the internet and copied both of `graphics` and `winbgim` header files into `include` folder also `libbgi.a` into `lib` folder, yet, when I come to run the source file, I get large number of errors.

Here is the source file;

```
 # include <iostream>
 # include <graphics.h>
 # include <stdlib.h>
 # include <conio.h>
 # include <math.h>
 # include <dos.h>


 class Planet
 {
    private:
       int x;
       int y;
       int rx;
       int ry;
       int color;
       int radius;
       int position;

       float displacement;

       char* Buffer;

    public:
       Planet( )   { x=y=rx=ry=radius=0; }
       ~Planet( )  { delete Buffer; }
       Planet(constint,constint,constint,constfloat);

       void Show( );
       void Move( );
       void ShowOrbit( );
       void GetNextPosition( );
 };


 Planet::Planet(constint _rx,constint _ry,constint _radius,constfloat _displacement)
 {
    rx=_rx;
    ry=_ry;

    x=(319+rx);
    y=240;

    radius=_radius;
    displacement=_displacement;
    position=0;
 }

 void Planet::ShowOrbit( )
 {
    setcolor(1);
      ellipse(320,240,0,360,rx,ry);
 }

 void Planet::Show( )
 {
    color=(random(14)+8);

    if(color==8 || color==14 || color==16)
       color=(random(6)+1);

    Buffer=newchar[imagesize((x-(radius+3)),(y-(radius+3)),
                        (x+radius+3),(y+radius+3))];

    getimage((x-(radius+3)),(y-(radius+3)),(x+radius+3),(y+radius+3),Buffer);

    setcolor(color);
    setfillstyle(1,color);
      pieslice(x,y,0,360,radius);

    setcolor(11);
      circle(x,y,radius);
 }

 void Planet::Move( )
 {
    putimage((x-(radius+3)),(y-(radius+3)),Buffer,0);

    delete Buffer;

    GetNextPosition( );

    Buffer=newchar[imagesize((x-(radius+3)),(y-(radius+3)),
                    (x+(radius+3)),(y+(radius+3)))];

    getimage((x-(radius+3)),(y-(radius+3)),(x+(radius+3)),
                        (y+(radius+3)),Buffer);

    setcolor(color);
    setfillstyle(1,color);
      pieslice(x,y,0,360,radius);

    setcolor((15-color));
      circle(x,y,radius);
 }

 void Planet::GetNextPosition( )
 {
    float angle=(displacement*position);

    x=(int)(rx*cosl(angle)+320+0.5);
    y=(int)(ry*sinl(angle)+240+0.5);

    if((y==240 || y==239) && x>320)
       position=1;

    position++;
 }

 void main( )
 {
    int driver=VGA;
    int mode=VGAHI;
    int error_code;

    initgraph(&driver,&mode,"..\\Bgi");

    error_code=graphresult( );

    if(error_code!=grOk)
    {
       restorecrtmode( );
       textmode(BW80);
       clrscr( );

       cout<<" \n Fatal Error  : Graphic Driver not initialized"<<endl;
       cout<<" Error Reason : "<<grapherrormsg(error_code)<<endl;
       cout<<" \n Press any key to exit...";

       getch( );
       exit(1);
    }

    setlinestyle(0,0,3);

    setcolor(7);
      rectangle(0,0,getmaxx( ),getmaxy( ));

    setlinestyle(0,0,0);

    for(int count=0;count<5000;count++)
       putpixel(random(640),random(480),random(15));

    settextstyle(2,0,7);
      setcolor(9);
    outtextxy(15,10,"Solar");
    outtextxy(16,10,"Solar");
    outtextxy(16,11,"Solar");

      setcolor(3);
    outtextxy(72,10,"System");
    outtextxy(73,10,"System");
    outtextxy(73,11,"System");

      setcolor(11);
    outtextxy(22,27,"Simulation");
    outtextxy(23,27,"Simulation");
    outtextxy(23,28,"Simulation");

    setcolor(7);
    settextstyle(2,0,4);
      outtextxy(10,465,"Press any key to exit.");

    setcolor(14);
    setfillstyle(1,14);
      pieslice(320,240,0,360,12);

   setcolor(12);
     circle(320,240,12);

   setcolor(4);
     circle(320,240,13);

    Planet Mercury(50,30,8,0.0175);
    Planet Venus(80,55,8,0.0155);
    Planet Earth(110,80,8,0.0135);
    Planet Mars(140,105,8,0.0115);
    Planet Jupiter(170,130,8,0.0095);
    Planet Saturn(200,155,8,0.0075);
    Planet Uranus(230,180,8,0.0055);
    Planet Neptune(260,205,8,0.0035);
    Planet Pluto(290,230,8,0.0015);

    Mercury.ShowOrbit( );
    Mercury.Show( );

    Venus.ShowOrbit( );
    Venus.Show( );

    Earth.ShowOrbit( );
    Earth.Show( );

    Mars.ShowOrbit( );
    Mars.Show( );

    Jupiter.ShowOrbit( );
    Jupiter.Show( );

    Saturn.ShowOrbit( );
    Saturn.Show( );

    Uranus.ShowOrbit( );
    Uranus.Show( );

    Neptune.ShowOrbit( );
    Neptune.Show( );

    Pluto.ShowOrbit( );
    Pluto.Show( );

    do
    {
       delay(25);

       Mercury.Move( );
       Venus.Move( );
       Earth.Move( );
       Mars.Move( );
       Jupiter.Move( );
       Saturn.Move( );
       Uranus.Move( );
       Neptune.Move( );
       Pluto.Move( );
    }
    while(!kbhit( ));

    getch( );
    closegraph( );
 }
```

When run it this file appears

```
    // The winbgim library, Version 6.0, August 9, 2004
// Written by:
//      Grant Macklem (Grant.Macklem@colorado.edu)
//      Gregory Schmelter (Gregory.Schmelter@colorado.edu)
//      Alan Schmidt (Alan.Schmidt@colorado.edu)
//      Ivan Stashak (Ivan.Stashak@colorado.edu)
//      Michael Main (Michael.Main@colorado.edu)
// CSCI 4830/7818: API Programming
// University of Colorado at Boulder, Spring 2003


// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                          Notes
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// * This library is still under development.
// * Please see http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi for information on
// * using this library with the mingw32 g++ compiler.
// * This library only works with Windows API level 4.0 and higher (Windows 95, NT 4.0 and newer)
// * This library may not be compatible with 64-bit versions of Windows
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------


// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                          Macro Guard and Include Directives
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef WINBGI_H
#define WINBGI_H
#include <windows.h>        // Provides the mouse message types
#include <limits.h>         // Provides INT_MAX
#include <sstream>          // Provides std::ostringstream
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------



// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                          Definitions
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Definitions for the key pad extended keys are added here.  When one
// of these keys are pressed, getch will return a zero followed by one
// of these values. This is the same way that it works in conio for
// dos applications.
#define KEY_HOME        71
#define KEY_UP          72
#define KEY_PGUP        73
#define KEY_LEFT        75
#define KEY_CENTER      76
#define KEY_RIGHT       77
#define KEY_END         79
#define KEY_DOWN        80
#define KEY_PGDN        81
#define KEY_INSERT      82
#define KEY_DELETE      83
#define KEY_F1          59
#define KEY_F2          60
#define KEY_F3          61
#define KEY_F4          62
#define KEY_F5          63
#define KEY_F6          64
#define KEY_F7          65
#define KEY_F8          66
#define KEY_F9          67

// Line thickness settings
#define NORM_WIDTH      1
#define THICK_WIDTH     3

// Character Size and Direction
#define USER_CHAR_SIZE  0
#define HORIZ_DIR       0
#define VERT_DIR        1


// Constants for closegraph
#define CURRENT_WINDOW -1
#define ALL_WINDOWS -2
#define NO_CURRENT_WINDOW -3

// The standard Borland 16 colors
#define MAXCOLORS       15
enum colors { BLACK, BLUE, GREEN, CYAN, RED, MAGENTA, BROWN, LIGHTGRAY, DARKGRAY,
              LIGHTBLUE, LIGHTGREEN, LIGHTCYAN, LIGHTRED, LIGHTMAGENTA, YELLOW, WHITE };

// The standard line styles
enum line_styles { SOLID_LINE, DOTTED_LINE, CENTER_LINE, DASHED_LINE, USERBIT_LINE };

// The standard fill styles
enum fill_styles { EMPTY_FILL, SOLID_FILL, LINE_FILL, LTSLASH_FILL, SLASH_FILL,
                   BKSLASH_FILL, LTBKSLASH_FILL, HATCH_FILL, XHATCH_FILL, INTERLEAVE_FILL,
                   WIDE_DOT_FILL, CLOSE_DOT_FILL, USER_FILL };

// The various graphics drivers
enum graphics_drivers { DETECT, CGA, MCGA, EGA, EGA64, EGAMONO, IBM8514, HERCMONO,
                        ATT400, VGA, PC3270 };

// Various modes for each graphics driver
enum graphics_modes { CGAC0, CGAC1, CGAC2, CGAC3, CGAHI, 
                      MCGAC0 = 0, MCGAC1, MCGAC2, MCGAC3, MCGAMED, MCGAHI,
                      EGALO = 0, EGAHI,
                      EGA64LO = 0, EGA64HI,
                      EGAMONOHI = 3,
                      HERCMONOHI = 0,
                      ATT400C0 = 0, ATT400C1, ATT400C2, ATT400C3, ATT400MED, ATT400HI,
                      VGALO = 0, VGAMED, VGAHI,
                      PC3270HI = 0,
                      IBM8514LO = 0, IBM8514HI };

// Borland error messages for the graphics window.
#define NO_CLICK        -1      // No mouse event of the current type in getmouseclick
enum graph_errors { grInvalidVersion = -18, grInvalidDeviceNum = -15, grInvalidFontNum,
                    grInvalidFont, grIOerror, grError, grInvalidMode, grNoFontMem,
                    grFontNotFound, grNoFloodMem, grNoScanMem, grNoLoadMem,
                    grInvalidDriver, grFileNotFound, grNotDetected, grNoInitGraph,
                    grOk };

// Write modes
enum putimage_ops{ COPY_PUT, XOR_PUT, OR_PUT, AND_PUT, NOT_PUT };

// Text Modes
enum horiz { LEFT_TEXT, CENTER_TEXT, RIGHT_TEXT };
enum vertical { BOTTOM_TEXT, VCENTER_TEXT, TOP_TEXT }; // middle not needed other than as seperator
enum font_names { DEFAULT_FONT, TRIPLEX_FONT, SMALL_FONT, SANS_SERIF_FONT,
             GOTHIC_FONT, SCRIPT_FONT, SIMPLEX_FONT, TRIPLEX_SCR_FONT,
             COMPLEX_FONT, EUROPEAN_FONT, BOLD_FONT };
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------



// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                              Structures
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// This structure records information about the last call to arc.  It is used
// by getarccoords to get the location of the endpoints of the arc.
struct arccoordstype
{
    int x, y;                   // Center point of the arc
    int xstart, ystart;         // The starting position of the arc
    int xend, yend;             // The ending position of the arc.
};


// This structure defines the fill style for the current window.  Pattern is
// one of the system patterns such as SOLID_FILL.  Color is the color to
// fill with
struct fillsettingstype
{
    int pattern;                // Current fill pattern
    int color;                  // Current fill color
};


// This structure records information about the current line style.
// linestyle is one of the line styles such as SOLID_LINE, upattern is a
// 16-bit pattern for user defined lines, and thickness is the width of the
// line in pixels.
struct linesettingstype
{
    int linestyle;              // Current line style
    unsigned upattern;          // 16-bit user line pattern
    int thickness;              // Width of the line in pixels
};


// This structure records information about the text settings.
struct textsettingstype
{
    int font;                   // The font in use
    int direction;              // Text direction
    int charsize;               // Character size
    int horiz;                  // Horizontal text justification
    int vert;                   // Vertical text justification
};


// This structure records information about the viewport
struct viewporttype
{
    int left, top,              // Viewport bounding box
        right, bottom;
    int clip;                   // Whether to clip image to viewport
};


// This structure records information about the palette.
struct palettetype
{
    unsigned char size;
    signed char colors[MAXCOLORS + 1];
};
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------



// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                          API Entries
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// Drawing Functions
void arc( int x, int y, int stangle, int endangle, int radius );
void bar( int left, int top, int right, int bottom );
void bar3d( int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int depth, int topflag );
void circle( int x, int y, int radius );
void cleardevice( );
void clearviewport( );
void drawpoly(int n_points, int* points);
void ellipse( int x, int y, int stangle, int endangle, int xradius, int yradius );
void fillellipse( int x, int y, int xradius, int yradius );
void fillpoly(int n_points, int* points);
void floodfill( int x, int y, int border );
void line( int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2 );
void linerel( int dx, int dy );
void lineto( int x, int y );
void pieslice( int x, int y, int stangle, int endangle, int radius );
void putpixel( int x, int y, int color );
void rectangle( int left, int top, int right, int bottom );
void sector( int x, int y, int stangle, int endangle, int xradius, int yradius );

// Miscellaneous Functions
int getdisplaycolor( int color );
int converttorgb( int color );
void delay( int msec );
void getarccoords( arccoordstype *arccoords );
int getbkcolor( );
int getcolor( );
void getfillpattern( char *pattern );
void getfillsettings( fillsettingstype *fillinfo );
void getlinesettings( linesettingstype *lineinfo );
int getmaxcolor( );
int getmaxheight( );
int getmaxwidth( );
int getmaxx( );
int getmaxy( );
bool getrefreshingbgi( );
int getwindowheight( );
int getwindowwidth( );
int getpixel( int x, int y );
void getviewsettings( viewporttype *viewport );
int getx( );
int gety( );
void moverel( int dx, int dy );
void moveto( int x, int y );
void refreshbgi(int left, int top, int right, int bottom);
void refreshallbgi( );    
void setbkcolor( int color );
void setcolor( int color );
void setfillpattern( char *upattern, int color );
void setfillstyle( int pattern, int color );
void setlinestyle( int linestyle, unsigned upattern, int thickness );
void setrefreshingbgi(bool value);
void setviewport( int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int clip );
void setwritemode( int mode );

// Window Creation / Graphics Manipulation
void closegraph( int wid=ALL_WINDOWS );
void detectgraph( int *graphdriver, int *graphmode );
void getaspectratio( int *xasp, int *yasp );
char *getdrivername( );
int getgraphmode( );
int getmaxmode( );
char *getmodename( int mode_number );
void getmoderange( int graphdriver, int *lomode, int *himode );
void graphdefaults( );
char *grapherrormsg( int errorcode );
int graphresult( );
void initgraph( int *graphdriver, int *graphmode, char *pathtodriver );
int initwindow
    ( int width, int height, const char* title="Windows BGI", int left=0, int top=0, bool dbflag=false, bool closeflag=true );
int installuserdriver( char *name, int *fp );    // Not available in WinBGI
int installuserfont( char *name );               // Not available in WinBGI
int registerbgidriver( void *driver );           // Not available in WinBGI
int registerbgifont( void *font );               // Not available in WinBGI
void restorecrtmode( );
void setaspectratio( int xasp, int yasp );
unsigned setgraphbufsize( unsigned bufsize );    // Not available in WinBGI
void setgraphmode( int mode );
void showerrorbox( const char *msg = NULL );

// User Interaction
int getch( );
int kbhit( );

// User-Controlled Window Functions (winbgi.cpp)
int getcurrentwindow( );
void setcurrentwindow( int window );

// Double buffering support (winbgi.cpp)
int getactivepage( );
int getvisualpage( );
void setactivepage( int page );
void setvisualpage( int page );
void swapbuffers( );

// Image Functions (drawing.cpp)
unsigned imagesize( int left, int top, int right, int bottom );
void getimage( int left, int top, int right, int bottom, void *bitmap );
void putimage( int left, int top, void *bitmap, int op );
void printimage(
    const char* title=NULL, 
    double width_inches=7, double border_left_inches=0.75, double border_top_inches=0.75,
    int left=0, int right=0, int right=INT_MAX, int bottom=INT_MAX,
    bool active=true, HWND hwnd=NULL
    );
void readimagefile(
    const char* filename=NULL,
    int left=0, int top=0, int right=INT_MAX, int bottom=INT_MAX
    );
void writeimagefile(
    const char* filename=NULL,
    int left=0, int top=0, int right=INT_MAX, int bottom=INT_MAX,
    bool active=true, HWND hwnd=NULL
    );

// Text Functions (text.cpp)
void gettextsettings(struct textsettingstype *texttypeinfo);
void outtext(char *textstring);
void outtextxy(int x, int y, char *textstring);
void settextjustify(int horiz, int vert);
void settextstyle(int font, int direction, int charsize);
void setusercharsize(int multx, int divx, int multy, int divy);
int textheight(char *textstring);
int textwidth(char *textstring);
extern std::ostringstream bgiout;    
void outstream(std::ostringstream& out=bgiout);
void outstreamxy(int x, int y, std::ostringstream& out=bgiout);    

// Mouse Functions (mouse.cpp)
void clearmouseclick( int kind );
void clearresizeevent( );
void getmouseclick( int kind, int& x, int& y );
bool ismouseclick( int kind );
bool isresizeevent( );
int mousex( );
int mousey( );
void registermousehandler( int kind, void h( int, int ) );
void setmousequeuestatus( int kind, bool status=true );

// Palette Functions
palettetype *getdefaultpalette( );
void getpalette( palettetype *palette );
int getpalettesize( );
void setallpalette( palettetype *palette );
void setpalette( int colornum, int color );
void setrgbpalette( int colornum, int red, int green, int blue );

// Color Macros
#define IS_BGI_COLOR(v)     ( ((v) >= 0) && ((v) < 16) )
#define IS_RGB_COLOR(v)     ( (v) & 0x03000000 )
#define RED_VALUE(v)        int(GetRValue( converttorgb(v) ))
#define GREEN_VALUE(v)      int(GetGValue( converttorgb(v) ))
#define BLUE_VALUE(v)       int(GetBValue( converttorgb(v) ))
#undef COLOR
int COLOR(int r, int g, int b); // No longer a macro

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#endif // WINBGI_H
```

**Errors**

```
302 40  C:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\include\graphics.h [Error] redefinition of 'int right'
2   0   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   In file included from C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp
302 27  C:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\include\graphics.h [Note] 'int right' previously declared here
28  23  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Error] expected ')' before ',' token
38  16  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Error] expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   In member function 'void Planet::Show()':
61  21  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Error] 'random' was not declared in this scope
66  12  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Error] 'newchar' was not declared in this scope
C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   In member function 'void Planet::Move()':
88  12  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Error] 'newchar' was not declared in this scope
C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   At global scope:
117 13  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Error] '::main' must return 'int'
C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   In function 'int main()':
123 38  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Warning] deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
130 17  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Error] 'BW80' was not declared in this scope
130 21  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Error] 'textmode' was not declared in this scope
131 16  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Error] 'clrscr' was not declared in this scope
133 8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Error] 'cout' was not declared in this scope
133 8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] suggested alternative:
1   0   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   In file included from C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp
61  18  C:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iostream  [Note] 'std::cout'
133 67  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Error] 'endl' was not declared in this scope
133 67  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] suggested alternative:
39  0   C:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iostream  In file included from C:/Program Files/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/iostream
1       C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp                    from C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp
564 5   C:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\ostream   [Note] 'std::endl'
149 27  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Error] 'random' was not declared in this scope
153 28  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Warning] deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
154 28  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Warning] deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
155 28  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Warning] deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
158 29  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Warning] deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
159 29  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Warning] deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
160 29  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Warning] deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
163 33  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Warning] deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
164 33  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Warning] deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
165 33  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Warning] deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
169 48  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Warning] deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
181 34  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Error] no matching function for call to 'Planet::Planet(int, int, int, double)'
181 34  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] candidates are:
26  8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] Planet::Planet()
26  8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] candidate expects 0 arguments, 4 provided
10  8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] Planet::Planet(const Planet&)
10  8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] candidate expects 1 argument, 4 provided
182 32  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Error] no matching function for call to 'Planet::Planet(int, int, int, double)'
182 32  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] candidates are:
26  8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] Planet::Planet()
26  8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] candidate expects 0 arguments, 4 provided
10  8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] Planet::Planet(const Planet&)
10  8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] candidate expects 1 argument, 4 provided
183 33  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Error] no matching function for call to 'Planet::Planet(int, int, int, double)'
183 33  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] candidates are:
26  8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] Planet::Planet()
26  8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] candidate expects 0 arguments, 4 provided
10  8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] Planet::Planet(const Planet&)
10  8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] candidate expects 1 argument, 4 provided
184 33  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Error] no matching function for call to 'Planet::Planet(int, int, int, double)'
184 33  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] candidates are:
26  8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] Planet::Planet()
26  8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] candidate expects 0 arguments, 4 provided
10  8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] Planet::Planet(const Planet&)
10  8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] candidate expects 1 argument, 4 provided
185 36  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Error] no matching function for call to 'Planet::Planet(int, int, int, double)'
185 36  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] candidates are:
26  8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] Planet::Planet()
26  8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] candidate expects 0 arguments, 4 provided
10  8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] Planet::Planet(const Planet&)
10  8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] candidate expects 1 argument, 4 provided
186 35  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Error] no matching function for call to 'Planet::Planet(int, int, int, double)'
186 35  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] candidates are:
26  8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] Planet::Planet()
26  8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] candidate expects 0 arguments, 4 provided
10  8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] Planet::Planet(const Planet&)
10  8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] candidate expects 1 argument, 4 provided
187 35  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Error] no matching function for call to 'Planet::Planet(int, int, int, double)'
187 35  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] candidates are:
26  8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] Planet::Planet()
26  8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] candidate expects 0 arguments, 4 provided
10  8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] Planet::Planet(const Planet&)
10  8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] candidate expects 1 argument, 4 provided
188 36  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Error] no matching function for call to 'Planet::Planet(int, int, int, double)'
188 36  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] candidates are:
26  8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] Planet::Planet()
26  8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] candidate expects 0 arguments, 4 provided

10  8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] candidate expects 1 argument, 4 provided
189 34  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Error] no matching function for call to 'Planet::Planet(int, int, int, double)'
189 34  C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] candidates are:
26  8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] Planet::Planet()
26  8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] candidate expects 0 arguments, 4 provided
10  8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] Planet::Planet(const Planet&)
10  8   C:\Users\user\Documents\solar.cpp   [Note] candidate expects 1 argument, 4 provided
```

Comment: Just copying header files randomly off the internet doesn't work. Header files only describe an interface (API), but you also need an according implementation that has a binary interface (ABI) that is compatible with your compiler. BTW: To copy the errors, try to click the error display and press Control-A there, try use the context menu with the right mousebutton or search for a build logfile.

Comment: Is this header file above compatible with my own Dev-C++ 5.11 IDE

Comment: thanks for  how to copy errors message

Answer (score 0):

Set `Project Options` -> `Parameters` -> `Linker` as

```
-lbgi
-lgdi32
-lcomdlg32
-luuid
-loleaut32
-lole32
```

Comment: Project Options isn't enable, Please tell me how to enable it

Comment: what do you mean by "Project Options isn't enable"

Comment: It is in gray you know not black  I mean it's allready there but it can't be hited by the mouse

Comment: its probably because some instance of your previously run prog are still in memory try restarting dev c++, let me know if it helps

Comment: I did restart it yet it can't be selected

Comment: Other thing you could try is create File->New->Project..., set name, select languane, and select a project type template

Comment: This time it works but still have these errors above

Comment: @rajnish As can be seen in the error output, it is not a linker issue. The header file seems inconsistent with itself "Redefinition of..."

Comment: Error output was added afterwards

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment because I don't have enough reputation, I have to leave an answer even though probably nobody needs this anymore.

The other answers are all correct, but I see that none addresses the one problem I know I encountered with `graphics.h`: it has an error on line 302 (in my version, which seems to be the same as yours) in the following declaration:

`void printimage(
    ...
    int left=0, int right=0, int right=INT_MAX, int bottom=INT_MAX,
    ...
    );`

I only left the line with the error, for clarity. See: `int right=0, int right=INT_MAX`? Redefinition. You can search for it in your post and you'll find it.

There it should actually be:

`void printimage(
    ...
    int left=0, int top=0, int right=INT_MAX, int bottom=INT_MAX,
    ...
    );`

Answer (score -1):

You are working on a `file`, not a `project`

First Download [graphics.h](https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/dev-c++/graphics.h) and put this header to `C:\Dev-Cpp\include`

Second Download [Libraries](https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/dev-c++/libbgi.a), extract file and put files to `C:\Dev-Cpp\lib`

And now, open Dev C++, and in File menu select new & new project
paste your code and go to Project option for Linker's Parameters

```
lbgi
lgdi32
lcomdlg32
luuid
loleaut32
lole32
```

I recommend you to use [Visual Studio and the same library](https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/visual/) for graphical programming

Also see [this page](https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/doc/) for some hints about `graphics.h`

Comment: in the past i have many problems with Dev and graphics.h .... just try to use visual studio ... it's better @alfadilahmed